# ASSEMBLY 8086-A MOV INSTRUCTION AFTER SEVERAL LOOPS BECOMES AN ADD

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I have a problem with my assembly program. It requires to computer the multiplication of every data stored in two arrays (whose length is 9) and store the results into a 9x9 matrix. The following is the code I wrote, but it works until the 6th cycle...then the instruction MOV AL,LIST[DI] becomes magically an ADD, and at the end the program shows this "unknown opcode skipped: 63 not 8086 instruction - not supported yet." Is there anyone who could help me???

```
LEN                 EQU     10
                    .MODEL small
                    .STACK
                    .DATA
LIST                DB      LEN 
DUP(0010b,0110b,0011b,1001b,1010b,0110b,0010b,0011b,0101b)
ADDED               DB      LEN-1 DUP(?)
TAB                 DW      LEN-1*LEN-1 DUP(?)
                    .CODE
                    .STARTUP

                    PUSHA
                    XOR BX,BX
                    XOR SI,SI 
                    XOR DI,DI
                    MOV CX,LEN-1 
external_c:         MOV AL,LIST[DI]
                    MOV DL,AL
                    PUSH DI 
                    PUSH CX
                    MOV CX,LEN-1 
                    XOR DI,DI
internal_c:         MUL ADDED[DI]
                    MOV TAB[BX][SI],AX  
                    MOV AL,DL
                    ADD SI,2 
                    INC DI
                    LOOP internal_c
                    ADD BX,18                       ;TAB is made of word, so 
                                                     I must do 2*num_rows
                    XOR SI,SI 
                    POP CX   
                    POP DI
                    INC DI
                    LOOP external_c

                    POPA
                    .EXIT
                    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like TAB size is not set correctly, resulting in an overwrite.
Try this change (adding parenthesis) around LEN-1 for TAB:

```
TAB     DW      (LEN-1)*(LEN-1) DUP(?)
```

There may be other issues. In the case of MASM (ML.EXE from Microsoft), I needed to make this change:

```
;   DUP(0010b,0110b,0011b,1001b,1010b,0110b,0010b,0011b,0101b)
    DB   0010b,0110b,0011b,1001b,1010b,0110b,0010b,0011b,0101b
```

Comment: The problem was the lack of () beside LEN-1. I was looking for something more complex.
Thank you so much

Comment: @SiBumBum - I'm also wondering if LIST should be starting with `DB LEN`, as opposed to `LIST DB 0010b,0110b, ... `. Also perhaps LEN could just be set to 9 and the code would use LEN instead of (LEN-1), unless the matrix was supposed to be 10x10 and not 9x9.

Comment: I made LIST in that way just in order to make some tries...I have to present the code in the most general form...so I'll delete data and replace it with `LIST DB LEN DUP(?)`